# Validate JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I aim to validate a JSON against a provided json-schema (draft-4 version) and print around what value(s) it did not comply.

Here is what I tried, not sure how to proceed further with validating JsonObject (as recieved at parsedJson variable) with the schema I have. For the method where I don't want to depend on an external library to validate, do I write multiple if...else conditions to check the validity of given JSON file? please suggest better approaches

```
import scala.io.Source
import com.google.gson.{JsonParseException, JsonParser}

object JsonValidator {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sampleJson = Source.fromFile("file\\path").getLines.mkString

    try {
      val parsedJson = JsonParser.parseString(sampleJson)
    } catch {
      case e: JsonParseException => println(e.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, writing a JSON parser is a quite advanced task thus I would strongly advise to start by learning Scala if you want to write one.

Comment: On the other hand, there are several well known libraries to work with JSON in Scala: Play-json, Circe, Jackson...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java-json-tools/json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) seems not to have been updated for some time. I'd probably pick one of the libraries listed [here](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html). These two seem to be most actively maintained: [everit-org/json-schema](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) and [networknt/json-schema-validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator).

`networknt/json-schema-validator` works with Jackson, which is one of the most popular JSON libraries in the Java world, so it should suit your needs. Here's a simple example of how you could validate a JSON object and print errors (I omitted error handling for the sake of simplicity):

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.networknt.schema.{JsonSchemaFactory, SpecVersion}

import java.nio.file.Paths
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

object JsonValidationExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // You can read a schema from a String, java.io.InputStream, URI, etc.
    val schema = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V4).getSchema(...)
    
    // You can read a JSON object from a String, file, URL, etc.
    val file = Paths.get("path/to/file.json").toFile
    val parsedJson = new ObjectMapper().readTree(file)

    val validationMessages = schema.validate(parsedJson).asScala

    validationMessages.foreach(msg => println(msg.getMessage))
  }
}
```

See a running example here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MnniQpKQQOaWa3ZvtTYriQ